# How to correctly initialize a computed variable in swift and XCode using MapKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

so I'm trying to store the device's latitude in a variable called userLatiude. I was trying to access that property later in the code but the variable is not created until after a property initializer is run. This causes the code to malfunction. I tried using lazy computed variables to fix this but I'm still running into errors. The current error is "lazy must not be used with a computed property".

```
lazy var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
return (self.locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)
}()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A computed property is *lazy* anyway, remove the keyword `lazy` and the trailing pair of parentheses

```
var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
    return self.locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0
}
```